# Как работает find_package()?

Tags: cmake

Я хочу устанавливать свою библиотеку из deb пакета и использовать в другом проекте на cmake
Для этого я сделал файл `FooConfig.cmake` и `FooConfigVersion.cmake`
Которые после установки пакета лежат в `/usr/lib/cmake/Foo`

Файл `FooConfig.cmake`:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@
set(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/Foo1.0/include")
set(Foo_LIBRARY_DIRS "/usr/lib/Foo1.0")
```

В приложении в котором я хочу использовать библиотеку я пишу

```
 find_package(Foo 1.0.2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
 ...
 target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Далее хочу собрать приложении, запускаю cmake и у он находит пакет Foo иначе бы он выдал ошибку. Но вот указать папку `include` у меня не получается.

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы занклудили папку под названием `Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS`. Вам нужно `${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS}`.

Кстати, `link_directories` устарело, вместо этого надо экспортировать переменную `Foo_LIBRARY` с полным путем до библиотеки.